# Problems using session + validation on CodeIgniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im working on CodeIgniter Framework. I used the library session without problems, getting data like this `$this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario')` this is ok.

But after uses form_validation :

```
  public function verify_password()
    {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Contraseña', 'required|trim|callback_correct_password');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password1', 'Nueva ontraseña', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password2', 'Repetir contraseña', 'required|trim|matches[Password1]');

            $this->form_validation->set_message('correct_password', 'Contraseña incorrecta');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'El campo %s es obligatorio.');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'El campo %s no es igual que el campo %s.');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->edit_password();
            } else {
                   $this->Opciones_model->save_password($this->input->post('Password'), $this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario'));
                   $this->index();
            }
    }
```

I get every time:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_Session::usserdata()

This happens only when I use validation + session, I tried few differents tries but always the same error.

Session is defined on autoload file (Its working).

Comment: Can you post your constructor as well as save password method?

Comment: usserdata should be userdata but that's besides the point. Where is your save password function? In this controller?

Comment: sorry I posted wrong code ( it was test ) , now is correct,  save_password is model function. the error is :  Call to undefined method CI_Session::usserdata()

Comment: Read my comment again. You spelled it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $this->session->userdata('IdUsuario')
```

Instead off,

```
 $this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario')
```