# session + form_validation CodeIgniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im working on CodeIgniter Framework. I used the library session without problems, getting data like this `$this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario')` this is ok.

But after uses form_validation :

```
  public function verify_password()
    {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Contraseña', 'required|trim|callback_correct_password');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password1', 'Nueva ontraseña', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password2', 'Repetir contraseña', 'required|trim|matches[Password1]');

            $this->form_validation->set_message('correct_password', 'Contraseña incorrecta');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'El campo %s es obligatorio.');
            $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'El campo %s no es igual que el campo %s.');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->edit_password();
            } else {
                   $this->Opciones_model->save_password($this->input->post('Password'), $this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario'));
                   $this->index();
        }
}
```

I get every time:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::usserdata()

This happens only when I use validation + session, I tried few differents tries but always the same error.

Session is defined on autoload file (Its working).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894677/problems-using-session-validation-on-codeigniter-php - Same question by the OP.

Comment: @DanielGB You already had an answer to this Yesterday in your Duplicate Question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems using session + validation on CodeIgniter php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894677/problems-using-session-validation-on-codeigniter-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss spelled usserdata change to userdata

Change

```
$this->session->usserdata('IdUsuario')
```

To

```
$this->session->userdata('IdUsuario')
```